# Cursor disappears while calling repaint in mouseMoved?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent, mousemove

I have a problem with drawing horizontal and vertical lines from the cursor position while the cursor is moving. The cursor seem to disappear.

I've attached a MouseInputAdapter to my swing component, which has a mouseMoved method which call repaint();

Calling repaint will cause a paintComponent(Graphics g) to be called. In paintComponent i paint the horizontal and vertical line:

```
Dimension dim = getSize();
g2.setColor(Color.white);
g2.fillRect(0, 0, dim.width, dim.height);
g2.setColor(Color.black);
Point pos = this.getMousePosition();
g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, pos.y, dim.getWidth(), pos.y));
g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(pos.x, 0, pos.x, dim.getHeight()));
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The cursor should be in the white area that exists between the big horizontal line and the vertical one and should be at the left of the big number 1.2434307...

When i move the cursor with my mouse i can see the cursor (crosshair) flickering which makes me believe my paint method is painting over the cursor.

Anyone know where the problem may lie?

As requested i've added a little test code.

```
public class TestApp extends JFrame {
public TestApp() {
    super("TestApp");

    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.getContentPane().add(new CustomComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setSize(300, 300);
    this.setVisible(true);

}

class CustomComponent extends JComponent {
    public CustomComponent() {
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));

        MouseInputAdapter mia = new MouseInputAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }

        };

        addMouseMotionListener(mia);
        addMouseListener(mia);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Dimension dim = getSize();
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, dim.width, dim.height);


        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        Point pos = this.getMousePosition();
        if (pos != null) {

            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, pos.y, dim.getWidth(), pos.y));
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(pos.x, 0, pos.x, dim.getHeight()));
            g2.drawString("where is my cursor?", pos.x, pos.y);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestApp();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i've just added a sscce.

Comment: Your cursor appears to be always present when I run your program. Sometimes it's black, especially when I move the mouse, and sometimes it's partially white when the cursor is over the lines as it appears to be xor'ing with the lines that it overlies.

Comment: Thanks for the SSCCE by the way, 1+ for that!

Comment: That explains it, the xor-ing that the cursor uses is strange, my crosshair cursor is a simple black cross of 1 px width. Xor sees the black lines underneath the cursor, so it displays as a white cursor, but because the background is also white it totally disappears. Solved it by using a empty cursor ;) Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's OK, you've solved your problem and that's what matters.